# DataReader::FromBuffer throws winrt::hresult_no_interface for custom buffer implemetation

Tags: c++-winrt

I've implemented my own buffer :

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h>

namespace Lib
{
struct MappedFileBuffer : winrt::implements<MappedFileBuffer, 
                                            winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer>
{
    void Seek(uint32_t);
    void Length(uint32_t);

    uint8_t* data() const;
    uint32_t Length() const;
    uint32_t Capacity() const;

    MappedFileBuffer(std::wstring_view filepath);
    ~MappedFileBuffer();
}
}
```

And I want to use it in the following way:

```
const auto buffer  = winrt::make_self<MappedFileBuffer>(fullPath);
auto reader = winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer.as<IBuffer>);

auto vec = std::vector<uint8_t>(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength());
reader.ReadBytes(vec);
```

Unfortunatelly, calling FromBuffer method throws winrt::hresult_no_interface exception.

What do I need to change in the implementation of my class to make the code work as expected?

Thanks in advance,
Michał

Comment: Could you please tell me why you need to use a custom buffer?

Comment: You also need to implement IMemoryBufferByteAccess, since that is how clients can access the bytes in the buffer.